# Is it possible, to make a plain-text attack on machine key encryption?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, encryption

I protect some strings with the following function:

```
public static string ProtectString(string input)
{
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    return enc.GetString(MachineKey.Protect(enc.GetBytes(input), null));
}
```

If i now encrypt a string, the attacker may now (i.e. an username), is he able to extract the machine key with the encrypted and decrypted values?

Comment: That depends on the encryption algorithm

Comment: @Shai pretty crappy algorithm if you could.

Comment: @Aron, much agreed (-:

Comment: @Aron So I can assume, that if it's a good algorithm, i needn't worry about it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack#Present_day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and found out, that the used algorithm is one of those: [DES, 3DES or AES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). And that algorithms are very resistant to plain-text attacks.

Based on Chris' comment, DES is very weak, so choose AES if possible.

But that's not a reason, to gift plain text values to your attacker :)

Comment: `DES` is extremely weak these days. There is a computer that can crack it in `3 days` or so. `3DES` is still acceptable, but below the standard. `AES` is the best one, and the `256 bit` mode is the industry standard. Just adding extra information here :)

Answer (score -1):

If you give a hacker the cipher text and the plain text, that is all he needs to brute force the crypto key.  That and a farm of high performance computers.

Really there is rarely a reason to send the clear text and plain text at the same time.  Just don't do it.  If you want to make the clear text tamper-resistant, pass the cleartext along with an HMAC instead.

Comment: That is not true at all. The attack being described by the OP is called the "[known plaintext attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack)", most popular modern crypto-algroithoms are not susceptible to it. What you are talking about is a simple "[brute force attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack)", if you are going to just brute force the key you don't need the plaintext to do it. For all keys except the correct key the ciphertext should decrypt to gibberish.

Comment: You missed the tongue firmly in my cheek when I said "that and a farm of high performance computers."   That being said, there are other plaintext attacks out there (e.g. adaptive/chosen plaintext) which can present a problem.  A clever hacker would enroll in the app several times and provide common passwords as the user name-- he would then be able to see what those encipher into and identify when the common passwords are used by other users.  Safest to not provide them in a manner where plain and cipher text are obviously paired.